# Android: Display Toast after sending SMS

Tags: android

I want to have some text pop up after pressing the send button.
Now, I have found ways of doing this when using other methods, but this is a school assignment, so I want to keep it simple and in line with the current level.

This is what I have:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    if(arg0.equals(sms)) {
        Intent c = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri pho = Uri.parse("smsto:" +text.getText().toString());
        c.setData(pho);
        c.putExtra("sms_body", "Text");
        startActivity(c);
```

I add the line:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This makes the Toast appear immediately, and before pressing the send button.

Is there a way to have it appear after sending using my current code?

Comment: Use startActivityForResult(c, 1) instead of startActivity() and show the toast in onActivityResult(int, int, intent) method.

Comment: why'd you write that as a comment and not an answer? just curious.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the message is sent or incoming message received using broadcast Receiver and after you send the message the receiver listen for action and  you can implement the Toast showing action

here an example show you steps to making it

http://www.vineetdhanawat.com/blog/2012/04/how-to-use-broadcast-receiver-in-android-send-and-receive-sms/